# search custom table in wp database with searchform

Tags: search

I need a search template for my custom table in my wordpress.

It should be one searchform and this searchform should search all
entries using the "LIKE" option.

The table in my wordpress db has 5 columns, "id,date,name,from,txt".

If I type "alexandera" in the search form, for example, the form should
search all entries and give the results in a table like
with 20 results per site

| id | date | name | from | txt |
|----|------|------|------|-----|
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | Alexander | Bank | Mail of Bank ... |
| 30 | 2021-05-01 | Alexander | Bank | Mail of Bank ...|
etc

or if I type Bank, it should return
| id | date | name | from | txt |
|----|------|------|------|-----|
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | Alexander | Bank | Mail of Bank |
| 30 | 2021-05-01 | Alexander | Bank | Mail of Bank |
etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a wpdb object in PHP. Its usage is explained in [manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).